# OpenGeo Suite Dashboard Not Showing Up

Tags: installation, boundless-suite, windows-7

I installed the OpenGeo Suite in my computer running Windows 7 Home Edition. When I installed it, I checked the box "launch OpenGeo Suite" and it ran. After installing several other software (XAMPP, Hamachi), the Suite Dashboard won't show up. As in there's no interface or taskbar icon. However, I checked the services tab in Task Manager, it was there and running. I tried changing the ports used by XAMPP, Skype, YM, and Hamachi, but the interface isn't there still.

Comment: which version of opengeo suite are you using ??

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a port conflict.

Check that the suite services (GeoServer/PostGIS) still running by connecting to PostgreSQL on port 5432. And GeoServer by navigating your web browser to http://:8080/geoserver.